# How to recognize original domain name from cname

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, cname

I have an mvc app(multi tenant) in wild card domain configured iis. I would like to configure each sub domain as cname entry for different customer domains.

now the problem is when the request comes from customer domains i have no way to find out who is the customer as i used to do it by checking the sub domain name.

so, the question is: is it still possible to get the original sub domain names while the request is from cname?

am i missing something?

Comment: Hi... did you finally solve this? I'm in the same situation :)

Answer (score 1):

All website requests ultimately just use IP address. Once the client-server connection is made the client specifies the name of the original host that they are trying to contact. Whether the host is a `CNAME` or `A` doesn't really come into it, that's all DNS work which is abstracted away from HTTP and the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Host` header, required as of HTTP/1.1, which includes the hostname and port being requested by the client (browser).

```
Request.Headers["Host"]
```

[RFC2616 Section 14.23: Host](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23)